# Doesn't work AJAX script data-type in cross domain request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://phpseverdomain/dynamic.php",
    dataType: "script",
    data: { type: "2" }
})
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

echo 'alert(1234)';
?>
```

This AJAX doesn't work when I run from different domain.

Comment: Do you get an error in the Javascript console?

Comment: Keep in mind that you only need to output the CORS headers for the OPTIONS pre-flight request. It doesn't need to be there on the POST request.

Comment: Check some other options: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are trying to do an AJAX request to a different domain, it is good to use `JSONP` datatype and retrieve the results as json 
**Example**

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://phpseverdomain/dynamic.php",
    dataType: "jsonp",// set Datatype to jsonp
    data: { type: "2" }
})
```

Comment: I want to run script when the ajax load, so i used script as dtatatype. This is not working cross domain request.